# pdfcomment and Evince

Tags: pdfcomment, evince

I was using `pdfcomment` to generate annotations in PDF files. But when I try to view the output PDF in Evince the annotations appear as a weird symbol that is not clickable:

[image: screenshot]

Any suggestions for fixing the problem? I am using Evince 3.4.0 with Poppler 0.18. I tried viewing other PDFs with annotations in Evince and those seem to be fine, so I think it might be a `pdfcomment` issue.

Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfcomment}

\begin{document}
\pdfcomment{hello}world                                                                                                                                                                                            
\end{document}
```

The generated pdf looks just like the screenshot above.

Comment: could you provide a MWE for folks to play with?

Comment: I have the same issue with Okular. Have you found any working solution?

Answer (score 4):

According to the `pdfcomment` author, this problem was due to Evince not following the PDF Reference on annotations. Evince seems to have a problem with the zero width that `pdfcomment` specifies for its annotations.

See also [bug 685334](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=685334) (Fixed on June, 2015 and available since Evince 3.18).

A workaround could be to directly use the `\pdfannot` command. I use this:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\annotate}[2][]{%
\pdfstringdef\x@title{#1}%
\edef\r{\string\r}%
\pdfstringdef\x@contents{#2}%
\pdfannot
width 2\baselineskip
height 2\baselineskip
depth 0pt
{
/Subtype /Text
/T (\x@title)
/Contents (\x@contents)
}%
}
\makeatother
```

(copied from [here](http://www.mrunix.de/forums/archive/index.php/t-62638.html))

Comment: Could you please give a full example? How should that code snippet be used in a complete latex file?

Answer (score 0):

That bug is already fixed in current versions of Evince and Okular.